# Post request not working with scrapy but works with requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, scrapy

Request code:

```
listings_url = "https://www.biltorvet.dk/Api/Search/Page"
form_data = {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "searchOrigin": "1",
        "searchValue": "22526899",
        "sort": ""
    }
response = requests.post(listings_url, json=form_data)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
```

Scrapy code:

```
class BiltorvetScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'biltorvet'
    listings_url = "https://www.biltorvet.dk/Api/Search/Page"
    form_data = {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "searchOrigin": "1",
        "searchValue": "22526899",
        "sort": ""
    }

def start_requests(self):
    yield FormRequest(url=self.listings_url, callback=self.parse, body=json.dumps(self.form_data))

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```

I get 400 on the scrapy request. I tried with headers as well but same result. Tried changing the parameters from body to json still no impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should serve the purpose:

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class BiltorvetScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'biltorvet'
    start_url = "https://www.biltorvet.dk/Api/Search/Page"
    
    form_data = {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "searchOrigin": "1",
        "searchValue": "22526899",
        "sort": ""
    }
    
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            self.start_url, 
            headers=self.headers,
            callback=self.parse, 
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps(self.form_data)
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.json())
```

Alternatively, you can try like below according to the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#jsonrequest-usage-example):

```
from scrapy.http import JsonRequest

def start_requests(self):
    yield JsonRequest(
        self.start_url, 
        headers=self.headers,
        callback=self.parse, 
        data=self.form_data
    )

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.json())
```